# Java button MouseClicked event return error when use showDialog

Tags: java

this is my code :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.stage.DirectoryChooser;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog;


private void btnOpenMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
         
        showMessageDialog(null, "Mouse Clicked");
         DirectoryChooser dirdir = new DirectoryChooser(); 
          
                File f1 = dirdir.showDialog(null);  // this is the problem
        /*
                FilenameFilter filter = (File f, String name1) -> name1.endsWith(".txt");
            
                String[] pathnames = f1.list();
            
                DefaultTableModel  model = (DefaultTableModel)jTableFolderContent.getModel(); 
                model.setColumnIdentifiers(new String[] {"Files Names"});
                Object[] row = new Object[1];
           
                // For each pathname in the pathnames array
                for (String pathname : pathnames) {
                    // Print the names of files and directories
                    if(filter.accept(f1,pathname)){
                        row[0] = pathname;
                        model.addRow(row);
                    }   
                } 
     */
    }
```

---

Returned Error :

jfx-project-run:
[echo] Executing C:\Users\MSKW7\Documents\NetBeansProjects\msk-watermark\dist\run456914622\msk-watermark.jar using platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_281/bin/java
[java] MyPath = C:\Users\MSKW7\Documents\NetBeansProjects\msk-watermark
[java] Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: This operation is permitted on the event thread only; currentThread = AWT-EventQueue-0
[java]     at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.checkEventThread(Application.java:443)
[java]     at com.sun.glass.ui.CommonDialogs.showFolderChooser(CommonDialogs.java:225)
[java]     at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.showDirectoryChooser(QuantumToolkit.java:1585)
[java]     at javafx.stage.DirectoryChooser.showDialog(DirectoryChooser.java:103)
[java]     at msk.watermark.frmHome.btnOpenMouseClicked(frmHome.java:127)
[java]     at msk.watermark.frmHome.access$000(frmHome.java:23)
[java]     at msk.watermark.frmHome$1.mouseClicked(frmHome.java:57)
[java]     at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
[java]     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6542)
[java]     at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
[java]     at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
[java]     at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
[java]     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
[java]     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
[java]     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
[java]     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
[java]     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4544)
[java]     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
[java]     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
[java]     at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
[java]     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
[java]     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
[java]     at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
[java]     at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
[java]     at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
[java]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[java]     at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
[java]     at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
[java]     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
[java]     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
[java]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[java]     at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
[java]     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
[java]     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
[java]     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
[java]     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
[java]     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
[java]     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
[java]     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Comment: The message “java.lang.IllegalStateException: This operation is permitted on the event thread only” tells you the problem:  Swing operations may only take place in the AWT event dispatch thread, while JavaFX are only permitted in the JavaFX application thread.  Don’t mix Swing and JavaFX;  the threading issues that doing so incurs are fairly complex.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use a JavaFX dialog in a swing message loop. Indicated by error message "This operation is permitted on the event thread only".

You need to either create a JavaFX application or stick to swing/awt components

Tip: `javax.swing.JFileChooser`